# Python login with requests

Tags: python, firefox, automation, python-requests

I need to download a large number of photos off a certain site. I however cannot download these photo's if I am not logged into the site itself. My first approach was to use requests module to download the photos and just continuously change the url's using code. This doesnt work because as mentioned previously I need to be logged into the website first. How would I go about doing this using requests or any other python module?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the documentation of `requests` here :

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

And the documentation for Authentication:

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/

In the example:

```
>>>from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>>requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>
```